# Package build with Android.mk misses many classes from local JAVA static libraries

Tags: android, build

I'm writing an android service that depends on 2 static java libraries: protobuf and jzmq.

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := appmonitor

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libprotobuf libJZMQ

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libprotobuf:libs/protobuf.jar libJZMQ:libs/zmq.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

The shared library files (.so) are available system wide.

Unfortunately the resulting package misses many classes from the zmq.jar which in turn leads to crashes within the service.
In other hand, package built with SDK in IntelliJ has all classes from the zmq.jar.

It looks like I'm missing some important options in my Android.mk, but which?

Comment: Is this supposed to be some extension to the firmware? Outside of that, `Android.mk` is the province of the NDK, which does not deal with Java libraries AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Kind of. Android.mk can be used to build java libs and packages too.

Comment: At best, though, it's a *very* distant third behind Ant and Gradle for command-line builds.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sure. But for convenience I'd like this service to be built as part of the rest system.

Comment: Hi Kentzo!  Since you're using Android.mk - I assume you're writing an app to be included in an AOSP image (inside of the packages/apps folder).  For including those two jars inside of the resulting APK, you have the correct syntax.  Can you elaborate what you mean when you say "the resulting package misses many classes from the zmq.jar"?  If you are using `mmm packages/apps/appmonitor` to build this part, then the resulting APK will have those two jars included.

Comment: Also, @CommonsWare, where is Maven on your list?? :-)

Comment: @ZachM: I was trying to be kind to makefiles. :-)

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Few packages are missing in the prebuilt jar